# Misunderstanding about apache and permissions

Tags: apache, magento, virtualbox, file-permissions, centos7

I'm configuring a server from scratch. I'm stuck in front of write permissions.

I'm trying to install a Magento installation and when I do the wizard I'm stuck in front these errors :

> Path "/var/www/html/magento2/app/etc" must be writable.

But, when I go to ssh,

ls -l in /var/www/

> drwxrwxrwx. 4 root apache 124 29 déc 14:21 html

(ed1: Previously I did chmod 777 -R html/)

(ed2: I'm on local server so, 777 rights are fine, don't blame me about it).

I install VSFTPD and I can upload files by FileZilla without problems.

I think, I have no enough rights only when I try through a browser. I looked into apache configuration, I set all to `Require all granted` and `AllowOverride All`. But I am still stuck.

Someone has already been in front of this case ? I'm sure, the solution is easy but I miss understand something about apache permissions.

PS : I'm working on my local machine with virtualBox on CentOs 7

PPS : My local virtual machine has 2 networks cards and is connected to Internet.

Comment: 1) check the permissions for `/var/www/html/magento2/app/etc`, not `/var/www/html`, 2) try disabling selinux with `sudo setenforce 0`

Comment: @DusanBajic Thx a lot ! I did *sudo setenforce 0* and It's work like a charm. Now I will read some documentation about this magic command :).